# Prevent file from being served when IFileSystem.TryGetFileInfo returns false

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

For my OWIN WebApi project I have my own provider for static files. This is how I register the file system provider:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileSystem = new MyFileSystem(),
    RequestPath = new PathString(""),
});
```

This file system provider follows a white-liste approach to only serve allowed files. For testing purposes I return always false here:

```
public bool TryGetFileInfo(string subpath, out IFileInfo fileInfo)
{
    fileInfo = null;
    _log.DebugFormat("Unable to serve file " + subpath);
    return false;
}
```

But every time I enter the path to an existing file, it gets downloaded. It seems that there is a fallback somewhere in the OWIN stack, but how can I prevent that?

Btw. I tried the `UseFileServer` method too.

Comment: Where are you serving the static files from? According to [the source code](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/StaticFileMiddleware.cs) it will move on to the next middleware (see `_next(environment)`) if `TryGetFileInfo` returns `false`.